# Сторонняя библиотека не подключается через стандартный инструмент Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, gradle

Столкнулся с проблемой: не могу подключить стороннюю библиотеку в Android Studio, используя стандартный интерфейс.

После выбора нужной библиотеки она появляется в списке, я нажимаю OK, и ничего не происходит. Студия не меняет раздел dependencies в файле build.gradle.

Подскажите где искать грабли.

Comment: Попробуйте: File -- Invalidate Caches/Restart.

Comment: Ни какого эффекта :( build.gradle не меняется

Comment: Вот видео проблемы https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rj0iexPsWbs

Comment: Да я понял, что Вы имели ввиду. Честно говоря не знаю, в чем может быть проблема.

Comment: Перепробовал все варианты, удалил Android Studio, rкеш gradle, Java, и.т.д. ни чего не помогло, студия не хотела обновлять build.gradle пока не переустановил windows , проблема не решена, кто столкнётся и найдёт решение прошу поделится

Answer (score 1):

Похоже проблема была в том что путь до Android SDK должен быть без пробелов.